# p5.js 27646: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, p5.js

I was coding in JavaScript, p5.js and came across this error line:

> 27646: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

and I don't know what this means since I am not very experienced with JavaScript. It is also suspicious to me because my project does not have line 27646 anywhere.

here is my code:

```
  var particles = [];
  const word0 = 'p5.js',
    word1 = 'is nice';
  var active, inactive;
  var cooldown;
  var font;

  function preload() {
      font = loadFont('data/LucidaSansRegular.ttf');
  }

  function setup() {
      createCanvas(600, 300);
      active = font.textToPoints(word0, 50, 200, 200);
      inactive = font.textToPoints(word1, 50, 200, 200);

      cooldown = 500;

      for (var i = 0; i < active.length; i++) {
        particles.push(new Particle(active[i].x, active[i].y));
      }
  }

 function draw() {
      background(60);

      noStroke();
      fill(255);

      for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        if (particle[i].radius < 0) {
           particles.splice(i, 1);
           continue;
        }

        if (cooldown < 0) {
           particles[i].forceToDes();
        } else {
           particles[i].fleeFromDes();
        }

        particles[i].update();
        particles[i].show();
     }

     if (cooldown < 500 && cooldown > -500) {
       cooldown--;
     } else {
       cooldown++;
     }

     if (cooldown == -499) {
       changeText();
     }
 }

function changeText() {
     switchActive();

     if (active.length == inactive.length) {
       for (var i0 = 0; i0 < active.length; i0++) {
          particles[i0].des = createVector(active[i0].x, active[i0].y)
       }
     } else if (active.length > inactive.length) {
       for (var i1 = 0; i1 < particles.length; i1++) {
          particles[i1].des = createVector(active[i1].x, active[i1].y);
     }

       for (var i2 = 0; i2 < active.length - inactive.length; i2++) {
          var p = new Particle(active[i2].x, active[i2].y),
            r = particles.random();
          p.pos = r.pos;
          particles.push(p);
       }
    } else {
       for (var i3 = 0; i3 < inactive.length - active.length; i3++) {
         var r = floor(random(particles.length));
         particles[r].shrink();
       }

      for (var i4 = 0; i4 < particles.length; i4++) {
         particles[i4].des = createVector(active[i4].x, active[i4].y);
      }
  }
}

function switchActive() {
   var temp = active;
   active = inactive;
   inactive = temp;
}
```

I hope you can help me :)
Thank you already!

Comment: At the beginning of the draw() loop `if (particle[i].radius < 0) {` should be "particles" and not "particle"

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to run. When I try to run your code, I get an error because I don't have the font you're trying to load. Either include the font file or modify your code so we don't need the font file.

But just looking at your code, this sticks out to me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
  if (particle[i].radius < 0) {
```

Here you're looping over the `particles` array, but then using a variable called `particle`. This is probably a simple typo.

I'm also suspicious of this line:

```
r = particles.random();
```

Here you're setting a variable that you haven't defined yet.

When your code contains multiple errors like this, it usually means that you aren't testing in small chunks. You should really get into the habit of working in isolation, only testing one small part until you get that working perfectly. That also makes it easier to post an MCVE if you do get stuck.

Comment: Aaah Thank You very much.

Comment: And I think the error message would be: particle is not defined if the "particle"-problem was the only problem..

Comment: @Steve Like I said, you're going to have to post a [mcve] if you want us to help you. We can't help you if we can't run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your **word1** string has a space in it.

*textToPoints()* doesn't handle non-printable characters.

Try a string with no space or split your string up into to strings and combine the points arrays afterwards.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it for ne

Comment: Awesome. Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0):

On Line 1 You define:

```
var particles = [];
```

But then you do:

```
if (particle[i].radius < 0) {
```

You defined the array "particles", not "particle", so JavaScript can't read the first value as the array "particle" doesn't exist.

### Solution:

change:

```
if (particle[i].radius < 0) {
```

to:

```
if (particles[i].radius < 0) {
```